# ABRecordCopyValue crash with SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, addressbook

I am trying to get contacts list like this:

```
CFErrorRef *error = nil;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = nil;

__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;

if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined ||
    ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

    addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
         ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
    return nil;
}

if (!accessGranted) {

    if (addressBook) CFRelease(addressBook);
    return nil;
}

CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

if (nPeople <= 0) {
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    return nil;
}

ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);

if (!allPeople) return nil;

NSMutableArray *contactsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:nPeople];

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < nPeople; ++i) {

    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

    if (!person) continue;

    ContactData *contact = [ContactData new];
    contact.firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

It is working on my iPhone 5s and simulator, but the build is crashing on the tester iPod device on the line with SIGSEGV:

```
   contact.firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Here is the stack:

3   AppSupport  0x34129a04  CPRecordCopyProperty
4   AppSupport  0x34129a04  CPRecordCopyProperty
5   AddressBook 0x2fd6ad22  ABRecordCopyValueUnfiltered
6   AddressBook 0x2fd6abc6  ABRecordCopyValue

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, the problem is that:

```
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
```

and

```
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
```

are giving a different number of contacts (so in your case `nPeople` is probably bigger than `allPeople`, which causes the crash). "source" doesn't seem to be giving all the contacts in the address book. Changing it to `nil` solved it for me. Also, to be sure I would do: `nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);`

The solution is very well explained by Jokinryou Tsui in this post: [ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople and ABAddressBookGetPersonCount return different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473968/abaddressbookcopyarrayofallpeople-and-abaddressbookgetpersoncount-return-differe/23192933#23192933?newreg=5dacce8539444d8fb5718f4a89551eaf)

(This is my first post, so I'm not sure if I broke any rules or followed the right procedure. I hope the answer helps!)

Comment: Hey Eric, welcome to stack overflow. Just to say you can use ` (backticks) to format code, or four space indents.

Comment: Good start! Thanks for helping me with this unpleasant and so hard to detect problem!