# Why using CFBridgingRelease, the count of result array is less than the original?

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook

I'm trying to use ABAddressBook and here is my approach:

```
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
self.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
self.source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(self.addressBook);
self.allPeople = [CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(self.addressBook, self.source, kABPersonSortByFirstName)) mutableCopy];
self.nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(self.addressBook);
```

The nPeople is 1008, but [self.allPeople count] is 2!!!

I don't understand why?!

Comment: This topic answered my question.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473968/abaddressbookcopyarrayofallpeople-and-abaddressbookgetpersoncount-return-differe][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473968/abaddressbookcopyarrayofallpeople-and-abaddressbookgetpersoncount-return-differe

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the default source is the problem. There are other contacts in other sources and I need to get them all. So in ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering method, the second parameter should be nil to include all of sources.

```
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
self.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
self.allPeople = [CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(self.addressBook, nil, kABPersonSortByFirstName)) mutableCopy];
self.nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(self.addressBook);
```